# The set of idempotents of a ring with Identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Problem: Let $R$ be a ring with identity, and let $M$ be the set of idempotents of $R$. If $M$ is finite, prove that $|M|$ is even.

---

Does anyone have any tips or hints to solve this problem? I imagine there is some relation between $M$ and $R$ that allows us to take an isomorphism of $M$, and then apply one of the isomorphism theorems.

Answer (score 3):

I will use the following Lemma which I leave as an exercise:

**Lemma.** Let $S$ be a finite set. If there exists a bijection $f : S \to S$ with $f = f^{-1}$ such that $f$ has no fixed points (i.e., $f(s) \neq s$ for all $s$), then $|S|$ is even.

Also, I assume that $R$ is not the zero ring, for which the statement is false.

---

Now, suppose $r$ is an idempotent. Then, so is $1 - r$ since
$$(1 - r)^2 = 1 - 2r + r^2 = 1 - 2r + r = 1 - r.$$
Moreover, $1 - (1 - r) = r$. Thus, $r \mapsto 1 - r$ defines a bijection $f : M \to M$ with $f = f^{-1}$.

We check that $f$ has no fixed points: Suppose $r \in M$ satisfies $1 - r = r$. Then, $$2r = 1. \tag{$\ast$}$$ Squaring gives us $4r^2 = 1$. Since $r$ is idempotent, we get $$4r = 1. \tag{$\star$}$$
But equations $(\ast)$ and $(\star)$ tell us that $2(1) = 1$ or $1 = 0$; this is not possible since $R$ is not the zero ring.